# QRCode of react-native-qrcode-generator crashing in Android, working fine with ios

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react-native project where I am generating a QR code. Dependency used is react-native-qrcode-generator. Its working fine in iOS but crashes in Android with  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 20188 (RenderThread.
I haave used hardwareAcceleration tag in manifest, crash get fixed with it but app starts lagging in another places, so don't want to rely on this tag. Please tell me how this issue can be resolved. Attaching logs here:

2023-03-02 19:30:34.608 20117-20341 HostConnection          com.example          D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7a8d1d29ae50, tid 20341
2023-03-02 19:30:34.608 20151-20186 cr_LibraryLoader        com.example          I  Loaded native library version number "91.0.4472.114"
2023-03-02 19:30:34.609 20151-20186 cr_CachingUmaRecorder   com.example          I  Flushed 1 samples from 1 histograms.
2023-03-02 19:30:34.612 20117-20172 cr_media                com.example          W  Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2023-03-02 19:30:34.622 20117-20341 HostConnection          com.example          D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
2023-03-02 19:30:34.625 20117-20341 chromium                com.example          E  [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(584)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2023-03-02 19:30:34.644 20117-20341 EGL_emulation           com.example          D  eglCreateContext: 0x7a8d1d29b690: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2023-03-02 19:30:34.654 20117-20341 EGL_emulation           com.example          D  eglMakeCurrent: 0x7a8d1d29b690: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7a8f315ef100) (first time)
2023-03-02 19:30:34.656 20151-20186 SystemServiceRegistry   com.example          W  No service published for: uimode
2023-03-02 19:30:34.678 20117-20341 chromium                com.example          E  [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(584)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2023-03-02 19:30:34.724 20117-20341 EGL_emulation           com.example          D  eglCreateContext: 0x7a8d1d29a3d0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2023-03-02 19:30:34.794 20117-20341 EGL_emulation           com.example          D  eglCreateContext: 0x7a8d1d29af10: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2023-03-02 19:30:34.822 20117-20341 EGL_emulation           com.example          D  eglCreateContext: 0x7a8d1d298690: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2023-03-02 19:30:35.102 20117-20188 libc                    com.example          A  **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 20188 (RenderThread), pid 20117 (ect.example)**
2023-03-02 19:30:35.497 20357-20357 DEBUG                   pid-20357                            A  Cmdline: com.example
2023-03-02 19:30:35.498 20357-20357 DEBUG                   pid-20357                            A  pid: 20117, tid: 20188, name: RenderThread  >>> com.example <<<
2023-03-02 19:30:35.540   603-20362 ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W    Force finishing activity com.example/.MainActivity
2023-03-02 19:30:35.729   603-2461  ActivityManager         system_process                       W  Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:0 in 1000ms for connection
2023-03-02 19:30:35.737   603-3342  WindowManager           system_process                       I  WIN DEATH: Window{e2f6367 u0 com.example/com.example.MainActivity}
2023-03-02 19:30:35.738   603-3342  InputManager-JNI        system_process                       W  Input channel object 'e2f6367 com.example/com.example.MainActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
2023-03-02 19:30:35.743   603-1762  ActivityManager         system_process                       I  Process com.example (pid 20117) has died: prcp TOP
2023-03-02 19:30:35.752   603-748   ConnectivityService     system_process                       D  releasing NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=267, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10158 RequestorUid: 10158 RequestorPkg: com.example] ] (release request)
2023-03-02 19:30:35.753   603-748   ConnectivityService     system_process                       D  releasing NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=265, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED Uid: 10158 RequestorUid: 10158 RequestorPkg: com.example] ] (release request)
2023-03-02 19:30:36.043   603-637   ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W  Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{31932b7 u0 com.example/.MainActivity t-1 f}}

Answer (score 0):

After spending 4 days finally got a solution to fix the crash.
I added animationEnabled:false inside Stack.Screen and it resolved the crash. This option needs to be added to both of the screens. Let say you are moving from A->B and B has QRCode implemented. Then this option needs to be implemented in A and B.

```
    <Stack.Screen
  name="AScreen"
  component={AScreen}
  options={{
    animationEnabled: isAndroid?false:true,
  }}
/>

<Stack.Screen
  name="BScreen"
  component={BScreen}
  options={{
    animationEnabled: isAndroid?false:true,
  }}
/>
```